# Using NSDate formatter, how to display day of selected date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Output format: date and day format is in the form of 05 March 2012, MondayNSDate *selected = [picker date];

In this code I got output in the form of 1989-07-03, I need to print the corresponding day.

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

//Set the required date format

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
// [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd %b YYYY, %a"];
//Get the string date

NSString* date = [formatter stringFromDate:selected];

//Display on the console

NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? The documentation explains this, so where do you have problems?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd %b YYYY, %a"];
NSString *theString = [formatter stringFromDate:theDate];
```

%b is the name of the month, %a is the name of the day

More info here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

`dd MM yyyy,EEE` like this ?
you can see more info about dateformatter [Date_Format_Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy,EEEE"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
    [formatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a fixed format, you should chose a [style](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/setDateStyle%3a) which will be localized:

```
[format setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
```

This way the user will see the date in the date format that he's used to without you needing to worry about it. For example, Americans would get dates like "Tuesday, April 12, 1952 AD" while Germans would get 
"Dienstag, 12. April 1952".

Answer (score 0):

NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"];

NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);

[formatter release];
```